# Memory leak from NSTimer?

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, nstimer

I'm developing an app and its essentially all up and running well. Obviously not well enough, though. When running the "Leaks" instrument, I'm seeing a lot of leaks from my NSTimer.

The NSTimer is started and stopped with a UISwitch. The memory leak occurs each time the switch is flipped to "OFF"

```
//PlayView.h
@interface PlayView : UIViewController {
  NSTimer *autoTimer;   
  // other things
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *autoTimer;
// etc...


//PlayView.m
#import "PlayView.h"
@implementation PlayView
@synthesize autoTimer;  


- (IBAction) toggleEnabledForSwitch1: (id) sender {  
    if (switch1.on) {
        self.autoTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                target:self
                selector:@selector(updateCounter:)
                userInfo:nil
                repeats:YES];

    }

    else {
        restart = 1;
        [self.autoTimer invalidate];
        self.autoTimer = nil;       
    [self.autoTimer release];
    }
}


- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
  // Do a bunch of stuff
}
```

What could be causing this? I'm certain it must be something simple and I'm just missing it...

Comment: From what you show here, there are no leaks. There's a programming error, though: Get rid of that `[self.autoTimer release];`. The only thing, protecting you from a crash here, is that you've nilled the property in the preceding line. Re the leaks: Could it be, that you are accessing the `autoTimer` property from somewhere else, as well? Like `myPlayView.autoTimer = nil;` or sth. similiar? That would totally explain this leak, since the timer would still be scheduled (and hence retained) on the runloop.

Comment: You need to also set `self.autoTimer = nil;` in PlayView's dealloc method to ensure you free the NSTimer when you change to another view/viewController and release this one.